# Codebehind function not being called by Ajax POST

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

My Ajax post is not running my code behind method and thus not returning any data.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="AspTest.Test" %>
```

*Test.aspx (Ajax script)*

```
    <script>
                $(".avatarThumb").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Test.aspx/MyMethod",
                        //data: {"s": "Some data passed through" },
                        //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        //dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert(response.d); //Returns "undefined"
                        },
                        failure: function(response) {
                            alert(response);
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Removing contentType and dataType does reach success but does not run the codeBehind method. With contentType and/or dataType active it will not reach success nor failure. FF firebug does not display any errors.

*Test.aspx.cs CodeBehind method

```
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string MyMethod()
        {
(*)         Debug.WriteLine("MyMethod called!"); // (*) Breakpoint never reached

            return "Method called!";
        }
```

Comment: Write [HttpPost]  before your method  named MyMethod.

Comment: @krillgar No result, is `runat="server"` even allowed there? It does not popup in intellisense.

Comment: @developer I do not have access to that class. I need the `Microsoft.Activities.dll`. Never imported a .dll though, I'll try it.

Comment: I am talking about   [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]    , if you have no access to the class then you won't be able to use this. Are you sure its a POST method? not get? try as              type: "GET",             in your jquery.

Comment: Sorry. I'm not overly familiar with Web Forms, especially anymore. I was just shooting in the dark, hence the comment instead of proposed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this. it should work fine

```
var SendData = {};
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Test.aspx/MyMethod",
        data: JSON.stringify(SendData),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.d);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            console.warn(result.statusText);
        }
    });
```

Your C# Method :

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string MyMethod()
{

    return "Method called!";
}
```

The above code works if ur page Test.aspx is at the root level of your project. If not change url parameter value like "../Test.aspx/MyMethod" based on the location depth of your file.

Comment: I get internal `server error` had to output it as a alert since `console.warn()` does not seem to output anywhere.

Comment: The server error came from the `data` attribute. `MyMethod` is expecting a parameter named `s`. I finally triggered the breakpoint so `JSON.stringify()` is the solution. Now I try to get some data passed between the server and client.

Comment: yes i removed the parameter from code behind. Now it works fine. It is always good to log java script errors in the console instead of alert. Because the result parameter in error function is an object and that you cannot expand and see in alert box.

Comment: `console.warn` does not output to VS console. Should I set that up manually?

Comment: console.warn is a java script command. so this will output to your browser console not VS.

Answer (score 0):

Change the data as follows and send the ajax.

```
   $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Test.aspx/MyMethod",
                    data: JSON.stringify({"s": "Some data passed through" }),
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    //dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d); //Returns "undefined"
                    },
                    failure: function(response) {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                });
```

Now the webmethod should matches the parameter send via ajax.

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string MyMethod(string s)
    {

        return "Method called!";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".avatarThumb").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Test.aspx/MyMethod")%>',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.d); 
        },
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
});
```

confirm the type GET or POST.

Comment: This does neither reach success or failure. Nor do I get errors in firebug.

Comment: check the url according to your project

Comment: The page is at the root of the project. It does have a namespace 'AspTest`. Anyway I solved it using the answer of Rakesh.